# WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException and MMF FileNoteFoundException cacophony

Tags: c#, ipc, mmf

Summary: EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting() and MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting() both failing but only on one PC out of a ~hundred.

Detail: I have a program that uses an EventWaitHandle to allow a client C# object to wait for a worker object to update some data shared through MMF.  This is in a program that is installed probably on a hundred Win 7 and Win 10 PCs.  Works great on every one *expect* on one stinking PC that a customer has kindly provided to test with... Acer Aspine V5 AMD A6-1450 1Ghz Win10 Home x64.

Here is the code that creates the EventWaitHandle in the client object...

```
var users = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
// Rule that allows anybody in the "Users" group to synchronize with us...
var rule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(users, EventWaitHandleRights.Synchronize | EventWaitHandleRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow);
var security = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
security.AddAccessRule(rule);

Boolean created;
eventWaitHandleForCommands = new EventWaitHandle(
    true,
    EventResetMode.ManualReset, // Ignored.  This instance doesn't reset.
    "MyEventWaitHandle78AEE98", // Unique name
    out created,
    security                    
    );
```

Here is the code that opens the EventWaitHandle in the worker object...

```
handleDomeCommand = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("MyEventWaitHandle78AEE98");
```

Here is the exception that occurs on that line when run on the Acer Aspine machine...

```
Exception = WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException
Message = "No handle of the given name exists"
HResult = 8013152C
```

Now it gets more interesting... recall that I mentioned using MMF as well?  So, I commented out the EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting() so that the worker object could move on to opening the MMF with the following call...

```
memMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MyMMF_78AEE98", MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite);
```

Which then bombs out with the exception below but only on this PC (about a hundred other installs it is OK!)...

```
Exception = System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message = "Unable to find the specified file"
HResult = 80070002
```

By the way, the MMF was created in the client object as follows...

```
MemoryMappedFileSecurity CustomSecurity = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
CustomSecurity.AddAccessRule(new
        AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("everyone", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
mmfDome = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("MyMMF_78AEE98", MMF_CommandOffsets.MMF_Size,
        MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, CustomSecurity, System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```

So, it seems this PC is jinxed *but* I've been around enough to know if it is a problem with one customers others will follow.

Other things I tried...

- Tried setting MS Visual Studio Solution Platforms from "Any CPU" to x86. Did not help.
- Thinking that this behavior might be due to the Acer Aspine PC being super slow, and the OS/NET-core might not have gotten around to creating the EventWaitHandle by the time my worker object opened it, I put 4 sequential message box pop-ups in between creation and "open existing"... did not help.
- Turn on/off Norton anti-virus... did not help.
- Install Norton anti-virus on another PC... my program works fine running with Norton on this other PC.
- Run as admin... did not help
- Tried putting "Global\" in front of the EventWaitHandle name... did not help.

So, looking for suggestions/thoughts.  Thanks!  /Chris

Comment: Looks like on this machine the server part is running as a System service whereas the other part runs as an interactive user. Did you try to prefix the names with "Global\MyEventWaitHandle78AEE98". That should also work on your bad machine.

Comment: I did try "Global\" in front of the EventWaitHandle name and the exception still occurred.  Interestingly, when I put "Global\" in front of the MMF name I get a System.UnauthorizedAccess exception on a "good" machine so "Global\" did not help on the EventWaitHandle and causes this exception on the MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew() even on a good machine.

Comment: This looks like a race condition in your application where the server part is slower initializing than you client trying to access the mmf and waithandle. Add and enable tracing on both parts to verify that the mmf and waithandle are created in the wrong order.

Comment: The object that creates the resources is in the same thread as the object that does the "open existing".  Do you think that the EventWaitHandle() ctor and the MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew() happen asynchronously to my thread inside the OS?  If so then they could be taking a long time while my thread moves from creating to "open existing"??

Comment: Update: I put a while( true ) loop around the EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(), caught the exception and just kept looping... the OpenExisting() never worked.  then put a Task.Delay() in the loop... still OpenExisting() was never successful.  Here is that code...

Comment: Whoops... not sure how you put code in a comment.  Does not mater since I'm going to ditch using EventWaitHandles, MMF and Mutex and implement this with a different simpler scheme.  Thanks for the help.